# registering python com server

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I have a problem when registering a Python com server, I got a message box that says :

> Invalid command line argument. This
>   programs provides LocalServer com
>   support for Python COM objects. It is
>   typically run automatically by COM,
>   passing passing as arguments The
>   ProgID  or CLSID of the Python
>   server(s) to be hosted

Although the same server was registered successfully on other machines that has different windows OS, I would appreciate any help.

### Thanks,

Sarah Abdelrazak

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but have you checked the value of the LocalServer32 registry key of your COM server. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683844%28VS.85%29.aspx

Any difference in the ways you've installed it on this machine? Does the path contain blanks?

I hope it helps